# How to pass an object to Ember.Handlebars.helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to find out how to pass an Ember object through Handlebars to a helper function. Any ideas of how to do this?

Data

```
groups = [
  {
    id:'as93-2dsa',
    name:'read'
  },
  {
    id:'dk20-d23k',
    name: 'write'
  },
  {
    id: 'mn20-8al3',
    name: 'execute'
  }
];
user = {
  id:'lk30-a8bk',
  name: 'Seth'
  groupIDs:[
    'as93-2dsa',
    'lk30-a8bk'
  ]
}
```

HTML

```
{{inGroup groups user}}
```

Controller

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('inGroup', function(groups, user) {

/** 
 * At this point I would expect groups to be and object and user to be an object
 * but both return classes
 */

  console.log(groups); 
  //Class {toString: function, __ember1418251045900: "ember646", __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object, constructor: function…}
  console.log(groups.toString()); 
  // "<DS.PromiseArray:ember646>"

  console.log(user); 
  //Class {id: "5CF3A051-12B4-436C-B43A-5696F2792B55", store: Class, container: Container, _changesToSync: Object, _deferredTriggers: Array[0]…}
  console.log(user.toString()); 
  // "<nfors-app@model:user::ember526:5CF3A051-12B4-436C-B43A-5696F2792B55>"

/**
 * I would like to access groups[i].id and user.groupIds in a way such as the following
 */

  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    if (user.groupIds.indexof(groups[i].id) !== -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

User Model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import EmberValidations from 'ember-validations';

export default DS.Model.extend(EmberValidations.Mixin, {
    name:       DS.attr('string'),
    groupIds:    DS.hasMany('groupIds', { async: true }),

    validations: {
        name: {
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 5 }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how are you loading the models on the html page? Your groups should have an array of users as part of their data, ie the hasMany/belongsTo relationship

Comment: opposite... users have an array of groupIds `groupIds:    DS.hasMany('groupIds', { async: true })`

Comment: `groups` and `user` are not classes. they are exactly the objects that you need. This is merely the  console output format for any object (other then primitives).

For example:
`console.log({prop: 1})` --> `Object {prop: 1}`.
`Object` is just the type of the printed object. Same as `Class` in your example, which is the basic ember constructor for all ember objects.

Comment: There is a problem in your code which is you are trying to get `groupIds` directly from `user` by `user.groupIds` instead of `user.get('groupIds')`. Same with `groups.length`.
I still don't understand why you are holding `groupIds` on `user` and not `groups`. can you share your `groupId` Model code?

Comment: @SethMcClaine ah yes sorry, thinking about it backwards. my bad

Comment: your trying to find which groups a user belongs to yes? If so would the best way not be to get the user, and then just get his groups? `user.get('groups');`

Comment: We have three tables User, UserGroups and Groups. UserGroups is a junction table. When we hit the api the user come with the usergroup objects as a sub object of user. What I'm trying to do is run through all the groups and highlight what groups that user belongs to. I need to run through the groups because the group name is not available in in the groupIds list

Comment: But that really isn't the question... The question is if I have an object how do I pass it through handlebars to the helper. `user.get('userGroupIds')` `groups.get('name')` or a get on any other property doesn't work from inside the helper. I can send in the use name through handlebars doing something like `{{inGroup groups user.name}}` but can't seem to retrieve an entire object

Comment: @SethMcClaine did you ever solve this problem, I'm quite interested in the answer to this or your hack if you came up with one.

Comment: @DonOmondi I think I just ended up writing everything different. I'm not sure, this was over a year ago, sorry

Comment: @SethMcClaine Its ok, I actually came across an add-on helper called is_in_array which does this beautifully. Some logic in the template really helps especially with caching now that Fastboot is stable. Cheers!